# What is an example of a Markov Chain with two stationary measures?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am trying to come up with a transition matrix for a Markov Chain with two stationary measures, but am not able to construct it. Would anyone have an example? Thanks.

Comment: AT least two or exactly two?

Comment: A linear combination of stationary measures is a stationary measure. Take MC on 2 states only with definite 2 self-loops - any $[\pi_1,\pi_2]$ would be stationary.

Answer (score 0):

The two state Markov chain with transition probability matrix $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
1-\alpha & \alpha\\ 
\beta & 1-\beta
\end{bmatrix}$$

can be shown to have an invariant/stationary measure.